# How to get rid of a textbox by pressing a button vc++?

Tags: visual-c++

How to completely remove (destroy) a textbox (not removing text inside it) by pressing a button in vc++ 2008 ?
windows form application ,, i created textBox1 and i want that textBox to disappear when the user hit a certain button (not by using visible function ,, i want it to be distroyed)

Comment: This question is impossible to answer as we cannot know which GUI toolkit you are using etc. Please edit your question to include all important details.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are talking about a C++/CLR application. If this is the case, you need to make your control not visible, and remove it from the controls collection of the container form (and assign NULL to any other variable pointing to it...).

Your code should look like this:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             this->textBox1->Visible = false;
             this->Controls->Remove(this->textBox1);
             this->textBox1 =  nullptr; // if you do not have any other reference to this object, it should be disposed eventually by garbage collection
         }
```

Comment: it looks like it worked ,,, but how to make sure that it's removed from the controls collection!! ,,, when put this (    this->textBox1->Visible = true;    ) it get visible again ,,, this means that it's not really removed! isn't that logical?

Comment: it is removed, I can assure you that, but it seems you forgot this part: (...)and assign NULL to any other variable pointing to it... If you follow this, you should not be able to reach the textbox anymore, or set it visible.